# Routing remote desktop connections - Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, routing

Without going into much detail, the basic setup I am currently working with involves connecting to another computer via RDP, and then connecting to another computer from that one using RDP. As you can imagine, this causes some notable lag. I'm looking for a way to minimize that as much as possible.

```
------------            ------------            -------------
|          |            |          |            |           |
|    Me    |    ---->   |  Middle  |    ---->   | End Point |
|          |            |          |            |           |
------------            ------------            -------------
```

I am required to do it this way due to current network security and structure, so simply changing that is not an option.

Is it possible to "route" connections so that I could connect from the middle-man computer without actually manually RDP-ing into it? To put it into more simple terms: is there some way I can connect to the endpoint machine directly from my client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reduce Connection Quality

[image]

In the settings for Mircosoft's built-in RDP client under `Experience` you are presented with the following options when you switch the dropdown from `Detect connection quality automatically` to `LAN (10mbps or higher)` or any other option.

- Desktop Background
- Font Smoothing
- Desktop composition
- Show window contents while dragging
- Menu and windows animation
- Visual styles

You can uncheck some or all of those for the first **and/or second connections** to see if that improves your experience.

## Expose second computer to the open internet

If you are able to access the firewall that the computer is connected to (**and your firewall supports this feature**), you can direct the port of the second computer (the default RDP port is 3389) to a different global port of your choosing. Then you would be able to access the second computer using the external ip, and the port number you chose, seperated by a colon. for example: `127.0.0.1:3344`

This won't work if the second computer is restricted to LAN access only.

## Things to consider

I do this quite often and I will say that I never experience lag from being multiple layers deep in RDP, **unless my connection to the first computer is slow.** I would say that if you are experiencing lag on the second RDP make sure the connection to the first RDP is solid and has enough headroom for the second.

Comment: I think this is probably the best possible answer, but i'll give it a few days to see if anyone has any input on how to do what I was originally attempting to accomplish, although I doubt that's possible or even necessary after reading this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Remote Desktop Gateway Server, it will replace your 'Middle' server. It works like a Proxy, and will route traffic from your machine to 'End Point'.

Here is a link that walks you through the steps to deploy.

https://ryanmangansitblog.com/2020/03/23/quick-simple-remote-access-solution-using-ms-rd-gateway-12-16-19-versions-ready-to-use-within-the-hour/